# Remove Interaction term with Factor values in R

Tags: r

I have following model:

```
> summary(mymodel.gml6) 

Call:
glm(formula = anumber ~ poly(coun, 2, raw = TRUE) + pharm+ 
    pharm:patus, family = poisson, data = mydata)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.4805  -1.7070  -0.7171   0.4482  12.6264  

Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 -0.2786022  0.0570305  -4.885 1.03e-06 ***
poly(coun, 2, raw = TRUE)1   0.2217527  0.0162746  13.626  < 2e-16 ***
poly(coun, 2, raw = TRUE)2  -0.0156164  0.0009538 -16.372  < 2e-16 ***
pharmyes                     0.3945798  0.0343844  11.476  < 2e-16 ***
pharmno:patusyes             0.0178374  0.0352272   0.506    0.613    
pharmyes:patusyes            0.2206909  0.0311678   7.081 1.43e-12 ***
```

`pharm` as well as `patus` are factors containing the values "yes" and "no". Now, I would like to remove the term `pharmno:patusyes` as it is not significant. I tried with the update method, but it did not work:

```
mymodel<-update(mymodel, .~.-pharmno:patusyes)
```

The questions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96587/how-to-remove-non-significant-interactions-from-meta-regression-rma-model) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172018/removing-interaction-factors) are slightly different as they focus on the removal of a complete interaction term.

Comment: you could ask an admin to move this to SO (stackoverflow).  those folks do much more programmy stuff there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R isn't letting you do it, because it shouldn't be done.  The interaction is represented by two variables; you need to retain both or neither.  It doesn't matter if the p-value reported on the line associated with one of those variables is significant, as you will get different patterns of significance with the same data with different ways of specifying the same model.  To test the interaction, you need a simultaneous test of both variables.  It seems to me there is something strange in your model but not enough information is presented to see, nonetheless, you should be able to do `drop1(mymodel.glm6, test="LRT")` to get that test in R.